# Why do I get 'UnknownHostException: session.minecraft.net' when attempting to log in to Minecraft servers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can't play online. I can only play solo. I have bought Minecraft so it should work fine, but, when I try to connect to a server, it says:

```
Internal client error: java.net.UnknownHostException: session.minecraft.net
```

I have tried over 20 different servers and it says the same thing for every single one.

Note: These are not Hamachi servers. I'm attempting a direct connection.

Comment: Your copy of MC can't communicate with the servers for whatever reason. This sounds like more of an issue with your network connectivity than with the game.

Comment: `UnknownHostException` is thrown when DNS cannot resolve an IP address.  It is usually due to issues with your DNS, proxy, or firewall.  Try connecting to a server using the IP address directly.

Comment: Why would Hamachi influence it? I'm just curious, I don't know all too much about these things myself.

Answer (score 12):

Quote from Kristoffer Jelbring, the Mojang web guy: "If you get an UnknownHostException when trying to join a MC server your DNS record is most likely outdated."

See [this link](http://www.wikihow.com/Refresh-DNS) for instructions on refreshing your DNS.

Source: Twitter @KrisJelbring