# Can't connect to Minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

Every time I try to connect to a Minecraft server it says, "logging in..." forever. 
When I scroll over the server in my multiplayer screen, it says no connection.

How do I fix this?

P.S. I have already tried making a firewall rule.

Comment: Do you get an error? [This question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/75652/cant-connect-to-servers?rq=1) may be of service to you.

Comment: Is it the same server or all servers you encounter ? Not only firewall rule could block it but maybe antivirus, router configuration, etc... Try to connect in your account via minecraft.net and one last question... Is your game cracked or legit ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try to log in here: https://minecraft.net/ If you can, this most likely means either your ISP is not providing service, or you're running the wrong version of the servers you're trying to play.

Answer (score 0):

Check your internet are you using wireless or an ethernet cable because wireless could have trouble connecting and you want full connection